# Probability density problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that on each day that I cycle to work, there is a probability 0.33 that I get wet because of rain. Suppose I cycle to work on 12 days, then what is the probability that I get wet in more than 2 days?

Give your solution accurate to 4 decimal places.

i dont know how to solve the distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability $P$ wanted is $1$ minus the probability that you get wet in no days, $P_0$, one day only, $P_1$ or two days $P_2$. The probability that you don't get wet anyday is simply $P_0=0.67^{12}$. The probability that you get wet in one day only is $P_1=12\times0.33\times 0.67^{11}$, since there are $12$ possible days for you to get wet. $P_2=\binom{12}{2}\times0,33^2\times0,67^{10}$, since there are $\binom{12}{2}$ ways of choosing the two days you will get wet. So, we have
$$P=1-P_0-P_1-P_2=1-0.67^{12}-12\times0.33\times 0.67^{11}-\binom{12}{2}\times0,33^2\times0,67^{10}\approx0.8206$$

Comment: what is 10 choose 2 from? and i got the answer which is 0.7911 is not correct thx

Comment: Sorry, misread the problem. It should be 12 instead of 10. I'll edit it.

Comment: yeah i got it thx a lot